# How put different colors at front and back sides of quad

Tags: opengl

Actually, my question is in header. I use "modern opengl" approach with shaders and buffers and I wonder is it exist any way to get different colors on two sides of one quad.

**Desired result** (back and front sides)

[image] [image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

GLSL provides the built-in `gl_FrontFacing` variable that determines if the fragment is a front-facing fragment or a back-facing fragment (is `true` if front facing) e.g. if it is a fragment of the front side of the quad or a fragment of the back side of the quad.

Within the fragment shader you can then check for this variable and set the corresponding colors per face direction:

```
if(gl_FrontFacing)
{
    outColor = color1;
}
else    // Fragment is back facing fragment
{
    outColor = color2;
}
```

Comment: note you could use this to select from 2 sets of texture coords or 2 samplers